# Comparing two functions (revisiting a deleted question)

Tags: functions, inequality

I came across this question yesterday just before it was deleted by the OP, but I've found it rather intriguing and so I'm posting it again, to the best of my memory, hoping for some further clarification.

**Problem:** Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers. Furthermore, assume that $a+b=c+d$ and $c<a<b<d$. Consider the following two functions
$$
f(x)=\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{b-a}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\frac{d^{x+1}-c^{x+1}}{d-c}.
$$
Show that either $f(x)>g(x)$ or $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>1$.

**My attempt:** Starting from the fact that $d-c>b-a>0$, I was able to show that
$$
\frac{b^{x+1}-a^{x+1}}{b-a}> \frac{d^{x+1}-c^{x+1}}{d-c}\frac{c-d}{b-a}  .
$$
I also know that $\frac{c-d}{b-a}<-1$ but at this point I'm a bit clueless on what to do and I haven't even used the condition $a+b=c+d$ (it might be the case that this is not even necessary, if my memory of the original question fails me). I've also thought about using some version of the Minkowski inequality. Any ideas?

**Edit:** After some discussion in the comment section, I've altered the problem to $x>1$, since at $x=1$ we have indeed $f(1)=g(1)$, given the condition $a+b=c+d$. I believe two interesting questions may arise from this, and potentially improve the problem overall:

- What happens in $0<x<1$?
- If the condition $a+b=c+d$ is dropped, what can be said regarding the two functions for $x>0$?

Any help to improve the main question is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that this first step helps much since it is merely showing that a positive number is greater than a negative.

Comment: On second thought... Is there a typo, am I seeing things, or does f(1)=g(1)

Comment: @sam_wolfe:  No, I think you are in the right spirit. I'm working the first few powers out and I see a few interesting tidbits around factoring $(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)(\sum_i a^i b^{n-i})$

Answer (score 0):

$(a^n-b^n) = (a-b)^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n\choose k} a^{n-k}(-b)^k$ so your function can be rewritten as $f(x)=(a-b)^{x} + \sum_{k=1}^{x} {n\choose k} \frac{a^{x+1-k}(-b)^k}{(a-b)}$. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: The problem is that it only potentially solves the case where $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Here, however, $x$ is a real number. Is there a continuous version of the binomial expansion?

Comment: Also, I believe your $N$ should be $n$.

Comment: Mark, I just approved your [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1242867), but remember that you should not use rude language (as in your commentary of the edit) as it counts as abusive behaviour on SE. However, I appreciate your contribution to improving the question post.